# switching to time edit mode of digital watch in statechart diagram in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, statechart

I have a question:

I'm dealing with a digitalwatch.sct state chart model right now.

When the bottom right pressed for at least 1.5 seconds, the digital watch should switch time editing mode.

How can I manage to do it, which kind of strategy or triggered event I should do?

The event for the bottom right pressing is "Buttons.bottomRightPressed".

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Even though i don't know the details of your statechart model i would 'blindly' suggest following steps:

1. add a state 'WaitForEditMode'
2. add a transition from some state e.g. 'ClockMode' to WaitForEditMode with Buttons.bottomRightPressed as trigger
3. add a new event bottomRightReleased to Buttons interface
4. add a transition with trigger Buttons.bottomRightReleased from WaitForEditMode to the ClockMode.
5. add another transition with trigger 'after 1500ms' from WaitForEditMode to 'EditMode'

Of course there are alternatives...

One more hint: if you post questions regarding [Yakindu Statechart Tools](http://statecharts.org) to it's [user forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/yakindu-user#!forum/yakindu-user) you should get answers without 4 month delay ;) ...